# Is it valid to replace system fonts via @font-face in CSS?

Tags: css, font-face

Today, I stumbled across a CSS hack that works in my current browser:

When an element uses a system font, like "Courier", then I was able to define a custom `@font-face` to replace the Courier font with a custom web font.

It's working for me; however, before using that kind of CSS on customer websites **I'd like to understand if this is intended browser behavior, or a glitch that might disappear any time or is not even supported on some devices.**

```css
.demo {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
}


/* 
 My Font Hack: Replaces Courier with "Roboto" Google Fonts
*/

@font-face {
  font-family: Courier;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v28/1Ptug8zYS_SKggPNyC0IT4ttDfA.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

```html
<div class="demo" style="font-family: Courier!important">
  This is Courier
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't *replace* anything, it just changes alias for the `Courier` font string for the current page where CSS is loaded in.
The reason you shouldn't do this not because of browser incompatibility/glitch, but because it changes semantics of `"font-family: Courier!important"` and down the line will make debugging font-related problems harder.

Comment: We find that a valid reason for this is to make websites GDPR-compliant: First set the font-family of text/titles to a websafe-font, then use CSS to change the alias for those fonts with a custom webfont (after the user confirmed the content)